# Passing object as response to ajax request in liferay

Tags: ajax, json, liferay-6

Hello i am a new in world of `liferay`.
i have a form that passes emailaddress via ajax request to `serveResource` method of my `portlet`.
on the basis of of that email address i have to search the corresponding user in `liferay` database and pass the User object as response back to my JSP page. How do i do that?
How to pass an object as response, from `serveResource` method to JSP page?
help me.

Comment: Are you using MVC Portlet for your Action class?

Answer (score 1):

Use herefor the methode like `writeJSON(resourceRequest, resourceResponse, json);`
See the full example at liferay source code: https://github.com/amusarra/liferay-aui-autocomplete-ajax-example/blob/master/src/main/java/it/dontesta/liferay/portlet/ViewAUIAutocompleteAjax.java